# How to open a new tab and close it almost immediately after running a script on the new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension, phantomjs

I am fairly new to Javascript and programming and have been trying to make a chrome extension to monitor the price of any product the user views on a particular site and notifies the user when there is a change in price. I'm scraping the DOM to get the price.
I want the extension to access the page every 5 hours and scrape the DOM and update the price.

The two methods I thought would help me do this is either use [PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org) or have my extension open a new tab with the saved URL, run the script to scrape and close it immediately.

**How would one go about doing it the new tab way or the Phantom way?**

I have tried window.open(url, '_blank') and setting a timeout but does not help. 
Tried using an iframe but not being able to access the document in the frame.

Please excuse me if I have not complied with the guidelines to asking a question. This is my first.

Comment: Maybe you should try another approach. Embed an `<iframe>` into your background page, or fetch the page with XHR if the content is not dynamic.

Comment: I don't see how phantomjs fits into the world of a chrome extension. You would definitely need a server where phantomjs does the scraping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the content isn't loaded dynamically, I don't think you have to open a new tab to do this. I would just make an HTTP get request to receive the page's HTML to scrape. This can be done with plain javascript

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

or with jQuery

```
$.get(
    "somepage.php",
    {paramOne : 1, paramX : 'abc'},
    function(data) {
       alert('page content: ' + data);
    }
);
```

Once you get the response, you can use [jQuery.parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) or something similar to turn that into an array of DOM nodes that you can scrape however you want.

Comment: Be aware, that you have to [add the domain to the config](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/xhr#requesting-permission) to let cross-origin requests through. You can run into [problems](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16939833/1816580), though.

Comment: Also, this won't work if the content is loaded dynamically. Then, an iframe or a real tab is the only option.